# safecracker login form not accepting login details

Tags: templates, safecracker, members, authenticate

I am fairly new to Safecracker, so forgive me if my question is stupid. On the following [site Click][1] Here when you click on the promo materials button, a pop up window appears requiring users to login with a username and password.

I have noticed the login form is not recognising my username and password. I am currently trying to login using my super admin. is there anything i need to select in the control panel. Also looking at the code i have submitted is this the correct set up?

below is a snippet of my code

```
{exp:member:login_form}

 {if logged_in}
<a href="{path="press-creative/pressKit/{segment_3}"}">Presskit</a>
   {/if}

<div class="tencol margin-bottom">
    <ul class="plain inset">
        <li>
        <label for="name">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" onclick="this.value = ''" id="email">
        </li>
        <li>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" value="password" onclick="this.value = ''" type="password">
        </li>

{if auto_login}
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="auto_login" value="1"> Auto-login</p>
 {/if}


        <li>
        <button type="submit" style="margin-top: 10px;">Submit</button>
        </li>


</div>  
    </ul>

     <p><a href="{path='member/forgot_password'}">Forgot your password?</a></p>

</div>

    {/exp:member:login_form}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put name="password" into your form. I think that should work then.